# Why System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure Occurred?

Tags: api, web-services, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In My **Xamarin.Forms** App, I am trying to call a free **API** using the following code:

```
 CallWebServiceButton.Clicked +=async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                string Result = await client.GetStringAsync("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/countries");
                ResultLabel.Text = Result;    
            };
```

Then I get the following Error:

> System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The
>   authentication or decryption has failed.)

I am using visual studio 2015, and this answer [Xamarin C# Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706055/xamarin-c-sharp-error-securechannelfailure-the-authentication-or-decryption-ha)
doest working fine for me, I think it is working fine for Visual 2017.

**َQuestion Update**

I Tested this On Visual 2017, it is working fine.
So this issue is only occurred in visual 2015

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin C# Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706055/xamarin-c-sharp-error-securechannelfailure-the-authentication-or-decryption-ha)

Comment: actually i think no, because same solution does't able to apply on visual 2015 till now

Comment: @EvZ , No duplicate issue occurred in visual studio 2015

Comment: I have tested your code in VS2017, it works. Please use VS2017 instead of VS2015.